# Boundary of Sphere $S^{2}$

Tags: general-topology

I would appreciate some insights as to how I can better understand the below following definition.

> Definition: Sphere $S^{2}$
>
> The 2-Sphere or just the sphere is defined as follows. 
>   Let $D^{2} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be the closed unit disk $\left \{ x:\left \| x \right \| \leq 1\right \}$ with the subspace topology.
>   Let ~ be the equivalence relation on $D^{2}$ defined by x~x if $\left \| x \right \|<1$ and x~y for every pair satisfying $\left \| x \right \|=\left \| y \right \|=1$.
>
> Hence, ~ collapses the boundary of $D^{2}$ to a point.
>   $S^{2}$ is the resulting quotient space.

I am unable to understand how the equivalence relation defined results in the collapses of the boundary into a point.

Insights are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The definition doesn't make sense to me. Any equivalence relation will satisfy $x \sim x$, by definition (reflexive property).

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/44/Disk_to_Sphere_using_Quotient_Space.gif Everything green point is the only element in its equivalence class, so that none of the green points get identified. The blue points are the points on the boundary (i.e., the points such that $\left|\left|x\right|\right| = 1$), so they all become identified.